# How to dynamically display new table values from a dropdown box selection?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an html table that needs to have new values depending on what the user selects from a dropdown box. The database is a list of people, and the dropdown box is a selection of floors of a building, such as 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc. When a new dropdown box value is selected, I would like the page to refresh and the table now be displaying the people who are on that floor.

It is an HTML table, and the DB is iterated through and filtered by razor code. Here is similar code.

```
<select>
    <option value="1">1st</option>
    <option value="2">2nd</option>
    <option value="3">3rd</option>
    <option value="4">4th</option>
    <option value="5">5th</option>
    <option value="6">6th</option>
    <option value="7">7th</option>
</select>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Floor</th>
    </tr>

    @{
    foreach (var person in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>@person.Name</td>
        <td>@person.Phone</td>
        <td>@person.Floor</td>
    </tr>
    }
    }

</table>
```

I would like to do razor code like this though:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Floor</th>
    </tr>

@{
   foreach (var person in Model.Where(person => person.Floor == selectedValue)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>@person.Name</td>
        <td>@person.Phone</td>
        <td>@person.Floor</td>
    </tr>
   }
}
</table>
```

The problems I have ran into are that razor is executed server-side, so assigning variables from js or anything client side is not an option. My question basically boils down to: How can I use a dropdown box to populate a table that is filtered with razor? If this is not possible, what other potential methods are there?

Comment: Usually for things involving server-side scripts combined with client-side scripts (such as JavaScript), you should use either html `<form>` tags to post data to a new page or the same page again (as a refresh), or use ajax or something similar in JavaScript to call that server-side script without having to refresh the page. I use PHP, not razor, so I can't give you specifics on that, but JavaScript simply does not execute server-side AFAIK.

Comment: @MaclainAnderson how could I use <form> for a quick html page refresh with the selected values?

Comment: @splindo You are trying to filter the table values with dropdown list selection, isn't it?

Comment: @splindo Where is your controller method code that is return the list of data for the table?

Comment: The table data is not filtered or returned from any code in the controller. The controller just has the methods for add,delete,edit,details etc. The filtering and DB value returning is done through razor code in the view. @TanvirArjel

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic form to POST data to a different or same page:

```
<form action="somePage.ext" method="POST">
  <select name="floor">
    <option value="1">Floor 1</option>
    ...
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Clicking on the submit button sends that data to 'somePage.ext', which could be a PHP script, a Razor script, or the same page you're already on. Just replace that file name with a real one. The data is sent with the name of 'floor' and the value of '1', '2', or whatever option you selected. What you do with the data is up to you or someone who specifically knows Razor, which I do not.